# CUDA not working after returning laptop from sleep

Tags: 14.04, drivers, nvidia, suspend, cuda

I have installed cuda 7 toolkit with newest driver, and it passed all the tests, it seems that driver is loaded, but every time when I  just put my laptop to sleep, and wake it up from sleep, cuda doesn't work anymore, deviceQuery

```
./deviceQuery Starting...

CUDA Device Query (Runtime API) version (CUDART static linking)

cudaGetDeviceCount returned 38
-> no CUDA-capable device is detected
Result = FAIL
```

Answer (score 16):

http://forums.fast.ai/t/cuda-lib-not-working-after-suspend-on-ubuntu-16-04/3546/4

You can reload the nvidia kernel module and it will work fine:

```
sudo rmmod nvidia_uvm
sudo modprobe nvidia_uvm
```

Notice though that this won't work unless all applications using that module are closed.

Comment: This solved my problem! I'm running with a Quadro K2100M on fedora28. Before trying this, I tried "sudo /usr/bin/nvidia-smi -pm ENABLED; sudo /usr/bin/nvidia-smi -c EXCLUSIVE_PROCESS" without success. I've always had to reboot in the past.

Comment: Closing all applications using nvidia_uvm by dropping into shell with `init 3` or `ctrl+Fx` plus restarting the display manager has worked consistently for me. `sudo systemctl restart display-manager` or `sudo service gdm restart`

Related Q&A: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1128057/weid-cuda-driver-state-after-forgetting-to-clean-up-resources-before-suspending and https://askubuntu.com/questions/1228423/how-do-i-fix-cuda-breaking-after-suspend/

I'm running 22.04, X11, GNOME V 42.9, nvidia-driver-535, CUDA Toolkit 12.2

Answer (score 6):

https://chuanwen.wordpress.com/2015/07/19/run-cuda-on-ubuntu-14-04-2/

What if cuda does not work after laptop wake up from sleep:

Put following 2 lines in your `/etc/rc.local`:

```
/usr/bin/nvidia-smi -pm ENABLED
/usr/bin/nvidia-smi -c EXCLUSIVE_PROCESS
```

Comment: Works like a charm! Thank you! (Mint Mate 18.1 - Nvidia GTX 770)

Comment: Does this prevent the problem from happening in the future? Setting these manually when cuda stopped functioning did not seem to resolve my issue. Thanks.

Comment: This worked for me!! (Mint 18.3, Quadro M1200 with 384.130 driver and CUDA 9.0)