# How do I fix CUDA breaking after suspend?

Tags: nvidia, cuda

So as the title says, everytime I wake my laptop up from a suspend, CUDA breaks, just plain doesn't work. I have to reboot my system in order to get it back. So to get it back after a suspend I have to run 'sudo rmmod nvidia_uvm' and then 'sudo modprobe nvidia_uvm' and of course that works, but as you'd imagine that gets old real quick. So how do I get it back permanently? If it makes any difference, I have a PRIME laptop with my Nvidia GPU always selected (940MX) with the 440 drivers.

Answer (score 10):

It looks like the `nvidia_uvm` module is not working well with suspending. CUDA can be used again if the module is reloaded:

```bsh
sudo rmmod nvidia_uvm
sudo modprobe nvidia_uvm
```

Unfortunately this does not work when there are CUDA applications active.

I have filed a bug report: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nvidia-graphics-drivers-460/+bug/1921477

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem on ubuntu. Recently switched to Archlinux. Followed this [tip](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/NVIDIA/Tips_and_tricks#Preserve_video_memory_after_suspend) on the wiki and it has fixed this problem on my gtx1650 laptop.

This way one can activate a new power management tool. See [nvidia documentation](http://download.nvidia.com/XFree86/Linux-x86_64/435.17/README/powermanagement.html).

My steps:

1. Create `/etc/modprobe.d/nvidia-power-management.conf` with `options nvidia NVreg_PreserveVideoMemoryAllocations=1 NVreg_TemporaryFilePath=/tmp`.
2. Update `initramfs`. On ubuntu that is via `update-initramfs -u`
3. `systemctl enable nvidia-suspend.service`. I think you have to manualy install the systemd service files first on Ubuntu. See this [post](https://askubuntu.com/a/1289842/235372)
4. Reboot

Answer (score 0):

This problem is closely linked to a question I opened [GPU not found errors](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1498498/gpu-not-visible-gpu-not-found-after-resume-ubuntu-22-04lts).

`nvidia-driver-550` with `cuda-12.4` works with cccplex's solution.  But there's no need to enable the suspend service in the newest drivers.

What you would want to copy and paste in the file `/etc/modprobe.d/nvidia-power-management.conf` is

```
options nvidia NVreg_PreserveVideoMemoryAllocations=1
options nvidia NVreg_TemporaryFilePath=/tmp
```

If you try to enable the suspend and resume services, you'll find that it's masked, **DO NOT** unmask it or else it gets removed.  As I suppose one might expect, the service is only utilized on suspend and resume.