# System fails to resume after suspension with NVRM errors

Tags: nvidia, 22.04, suspend, cuda

I have 22.04 LTS, and an nvidia 4070 card. I installed the driver via Cuda toolkit v12.3, and blacklisted nouveau (which doesn't even fully work with 4070 still). When I suspend the system, and try to resume, I get the following errors:

```
[41.212199] NVRM nbsiReadRegistryDword: osReadRegistryDword called in Sleep path can cause excess delays!
[41.212201] NVRM nvAssertFailedNoLog: Assertion failed: 0 @ nbsi_osrg.c:107
```

which repeat a bunch of times. And then the system doesn't resume and I have to force reboot the computer. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I'm running into similar issues with different nvidia cards, drivers and CUDA Toolkit versions. Next approach I'll try is this:

```
sudo rmmod nvidia_uvm
sudo modprobe nvidia_uvm
```

Have you had any luck with the answers to these similar questions?

[CUDA not working after returning laptop from sleep](https://askubuntu.com/questions/607118/cuda-not-working-after-returning-laptop-from-sleep/)

[How do I fix CUDA breaking after suspend?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1228423/how-do-i-fix-cuda-breaking-after-suspend/)

[Weid cuda driver state after forgetting to clean up resources before suspending the computer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1128057/weid-cuda-driver-state-after-forgetting-to-clean-up-resources-before-suspending)

Comment: Removing and re-probing nvidia_uvm works to address CUDA errors after resume. Details here  https://askubuntu.com/a/1506973/941887